# org.hibernate.MappingException: No Dialect mapping for JDBC type: 1632665994

Tags: hibernate, dialect, mappingexception

I encounter this problem when I develop a web app. I use hibernate 4.3.8.Final and JPA2.1; I don't know what's wrong. I turn the 'org.hibernate' logger in my logback under 'DEBUG' level and append to a file, nothing useful I can find in the log file. Anybody know how to solve this? Or can someone suggest how to debug this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check you hibernate configuration file for dialect configuration

**Sample dialect Property**

```
<property name="dialect">dialect for your database </property>
<property name="connection.driver_class">dialect for your database</property>
```

**For Oracle Dialect**

```
<property name="dialect">org.hibernate.dialect.Oracle10gDialect</property>
  <property name="connection.driver_class">oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver</property>
```

Refer the link for Hibernate supported database and dialects [Hibernate Dialect](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/4.3/manual/en-US/html/ch03.html#configuration-optional-dialects)

Comment: My configuration is <prop key="hibernate.dialect">org.hibernate.dialect.MySQL57InnoDBDialect</prop> with MySQL version 5.7. But this does not work.

Comment: This is caused by the 'java.lang.Byte' field in my entity. MySQL Dialect dose not support the mapping. I change the 'Byte' field to 'Integer', It's work perfectly. Thanks for your recommend.